# Angular upload onchange event :getting empty file in server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

Here is my code to upload file to server on input change

```
    $scope.uploadImage = function (f) { 
        $http.post('/art',{'image':f},{headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}}).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }); 
    }
```

but i will get empty files in server however i **check my serverside code with normal fileupload** it works fine without any problem

**Serverside**

```
//get empty in angular upload 
     console.log(req.file('image'));

        req.file('image').upload({
                // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
                maxBytes: 10000000
            },function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {

            return res.json({
                'status':uploadedFiles
            })
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" ng-model="art.artImage" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this.files)" name="artImage" id="artImage">
```

I believe its problem with `content-type` in angular http post request

Comment: What is the value of "f" you see when you debug  $scope.uploadImage function.

Comment: Json object that contains file information like this `1
0
:
File
lastModified
:
1493977671608
lastModifiedDate
:
Fri May 05 2017 15:17:51 GMT+0530 (IST)
__proto__
:
Object
name
:
"1493977658097.jpeg"
size
:
10286
type
:
"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath
:
""
__proto__
:
File`

Comment: @Jabaa Can you try `f` instead of `{'image':f}`? This can cause content type changing to application/json.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash still the same error

Comment: @Jabaa What error you have? Have you checked the content type? What is it in this case?

Comment: Content type is `multipart-formdata` this line `console.log(req.file('image'))`; i got an exception bcz of the input file is empty

Comment: @Jabaa What is in `req.files`? This is expected to be empty `req.file('image')` since we've replaced `{'image':f}` with `f`.

Comment: that contains the input file equivalent to php `$_FILES`

Comment: @Jabaa so why you can't get your uploaded file from `req.files`?

Answer (score 0):

when the input type is `file` file will not attach the model. You need a workaround like this.

```
.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

change the input like

```
<input type="file" fileread="art.artImage" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this.files)" 
name="artImage" id="artImage">
```

use the `multipart` header in your request

```
$http.post('/art', {
    'image': art.artImage
}, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
    }
})
```

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: Its not worked also my content type still application/json its not changed

Comment: Now the content type changed but  still the empty result

Answer (score 0):

Please try this , avoid using onload in HTML tag for file :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "myApp">

  <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
     <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
     <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
  </div>

  <script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);

     myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })            
           .success(function(){
               alert("Done");
           })            
           .error(function(){
               alert("Sorry");
           });
        }
     }]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "/art";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
     }]);

  </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried this same error the form data getting empty object

Comment: As per the json you explained in your comments , I suppose you will have to use the name of the file instead of entire file object. So please use "f.name" instead of "f" . You file name is  "1493977658097.jpeg",JSON of "f" has {.....name : "1493977658097.jpeg"...}

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-fileUpload` lib for angularjs

My HTML

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-controller="commentCtrl" name="form">
    <a href="" type="file" class="custom-height"><img src="source/assets/images/icons/icofileattached.png" class="attachmentpng-height"  ngf-select="uploadFiles($file)" ng-model="files"/></a>
    <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised custom-submit-button" ng-click="MakeComments()"> SUBMIT </md-button>
    </form>
```

My Controller code

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(file) {
            console.log(file);
            $scope.fileData = file;
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            Restangular.one('/api/files/end points').withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
                .customPOST(fd, '', undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined})
        };
```